# How to get filenames of an archive in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

How can I get a list with of all filenames of an archive in Python3?
The archive is a variable of type ZipFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple , you call zip.namelist() and iterate over each entry.